# Should gun recoil be an animation or script?

Tags: animation

Should recoil for a rapid fire gun be be done through an animation or a script? I want the recoil to increase as I continuously fire, like a lot of FPS games do.

I was initially considering achieving this through a script in unity that rotates the gun slightly each time I fire, but I realized that since I plan to have most rapid fire guns be 2 handed weapons, at some point, the left hand won't be on the weapon.

However, since I want the recoil to increase as I fire, I'm not sure how to achieve this in an animation.

How is recoil typically done? Input on this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Seems like most people use scripts, heres a tutorial for making a recoil script in unity. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hyQ2rPkMDY

Comment: @Nascent Space Do you have any suggestions on how to keep the left hand on the gun, since I have arms that are gripping the gun? I plan to have the recoil a little bit more powerful than the guy in the vide, and I don't want  the left hand to be stationary while the gun is moving.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have enough experience with animation or unity to give you any solid advice on this, but I do believe there would be some way to add it with the script.

Comment: Hello, this would be more appropriate over on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It looks like its been cross-posted, so it now appears twice in web searches. Should this question be removed?